# Mapping Keys between Types

Tags: typescript

Consider the Typescript below.  We have two interfaces, both with the same fields that we want to map between.  I.e. I want to take an instance of `SerialisedModel` and convert it to a `Model`.  In the example below if I rename fields on `SerialisedModel` or `Model`, the compiler will not complain and we'll have runtime problems.

What I really want to do is declare `Model` to have the same keys as `SerialisedModel`, BUT allow different values.  E.g. `age` is a `string` in `SerialisedModel` but is a `number` in `Model`.

I can't seem to figure out how to do this with any Typescript syntax. We've managed to get it somewhat working with Mapped types, but it always ends up with values being `any`.  Any ideas?

```js
interface SerialisedModel {
  name: string;
  age: string;
  dateOfBirth: string;
}

interface Model {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  dateOfBirth: Date
}

const f: SerialisedModel = // instanciate SerialisedModel;
let b = {} as Model;
Object.keys(f).forEach(key => {
  const mapped = f[key] // then do some mapping to convert values
  b[key] = mapped;
})
```

Comment: First of all, Foo and Bar are not classes, they cannot be newed. Another thing is that it's unclear how they should be mapped. They are clearly incompatible. `age` is number vs string[].

Comment: Apologies, I didn't mean to instanciate them.  It doesn't matter how they are mapped, it's just an example.  What I want to ensure is that the compiler ensures that for both types they have the same keys irrespective of what types the fields have.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Foo age cannot be mapped to Bar age, they are different types. Do you expect type incompatibility to cause type error then? Can you provide more specific example that shows what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Example updated.  Imagine a case where we want to serialise a model to some persistance store.  Let's imagine it only accepts strings.  When I hydrate that model, I have a mechanism of doing that in a generic way, but I want to make sure that if fields are added to `SerialisedModel` I get a compiler error saying they're missing from Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm confused about what you're really trying to achieve here.  Where are you seeing "it always ends up with values being `any`"?  I don't see that in my or your code.

If all you are trying to do is have the compiler yell at you if two types have different keys, you can do something like this:

```
type RequireSameKeys<T extends Record<keyof U, any>, U extends Record<keyof T, any>> = true

type VerifyModelTypes = RequireSameKeys<SerialisedModel, Model>; // okay?
```

If `VerifyModelTypes` has no error, then `SerialisedModel` and `Model` have exactly the same keys.  Let's see:

```
interface Model {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  dateOfBirth: Date
}

interface SerialisedModel {
  name: string;
  age: string;
  dateOfBrith: string; // Hppay Brithday To Yuo
}

type VerifyModelTypes = RequireSameKeys<SerialisedModel, Model>; // error!
//  Property 'dateOfBirth' is missing in type 'SerialisedModel'.
```

Whoops, let's fix that:

```
interface SerialisedModel {
  name: string;
  age: string;
  dateOfBirth: string; // fixed
}

type VerifyModelTypes = RequireSameKeys<SerialisedModel, Model>; // okay
```

It's happy now.

---

But since `SerialisedModel` seems to be a straightforward mapping of `Model`, you should indeed be able to use mapped types to define it:

```
type _SM = { [K in keyof Model]: string };
interface SerialisedModel extends _SM {};  // same as before
```

and then make a generic processor function to convert between them:

```
function makeProcessor<T extends Record<keyof T & keyof U, any>, 
  U extends Record<keyof T & keyof U, any>>(
  processors: { [K in keyof T & keyof U]: (x: T[K]) => U[K] }
): (t: T) => U {
  return (t: T) => {
    const ret = {} as U;
    // note Object.keys() returns string[], not (keyof T)[], so we assert
    Object.keys(processors).forEach((k: keyof T) => {
      ret[k] = processors[k](t[k]);
    });
    return ret;
  }
}
```

Here's how you'd use it:

```
const deserialise = makeProcessor<SerialisedModel, Model>({
  age: a => +a,
  name: n => n,
  dateOfBirth: d => new Date(+d)
});

const serialise = makeProcessor<Model, SerialisedModel>({
  age: a => "" + a,
  name: n => n,
  dateOfBirth: d => "" + d.getTime()
})

const model: Model = {
  name: "Gabriel Jarret",
  age: 48,
  dateOfBirth: new Date(0)
}

console.log(model.name); // "Gabriel Jarret"
console.log(model.age); // 48 
console.log(model.dateOfBirth); // Date 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z

const serialisedModel = serialise(model);

console.log(serialisedModel.name); // "Gabriel Jarret"
console.log(serialisedModel.age); // "48"
console.log(serialisedModel.dateOfBirth); // "0"

const deserialisedModel = deserialise(serialisedModel);

console.log(deserialisedModel.name === model.name); // true
console.log(deserialisedModel.age === model.age); // true
console.log(deserialisedModel.dateOfBirth.getTime() === 
  model.dateOfBirth.getTime()); // true
```

That all looks good to me.  Does that help?  If you are continuing to see a problem, please include specific code where errors are occurring.  Otherwise I'm  just making guesses about what you need.  Anyway, good luck!

Comment: Realised I accepted this but didn't say thanks for the great answer.  So thanks!